# Adding application to 'Open with other applications' dialog

Tags: ubuntu, komodo

I installed Komodo earlier today and am unable to locate it in the "Open with other applications" dialog. The application works as intended other than this.

Using ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URL from answer is down

Here is how to do it:

Create file in ~/.local/share/applications named
`XXX.desktop` e.g flashplayer.desktop

Content of file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/home/executable-path %f
Name=flashplayer
Comment=Custom definition for flashplayer
NoDisplay=true
```

**Note:** the `%f` after the path to the executable is necessary for the application to appear in the 'Open with' menu.

In nautilus,

```
- right click on file
- open with other applications
- show other applications
- select the one created e.g flashplayer
```

Also update the properties / open-with and set it as a default

Comment: Thanks for this - the best answer I've found to this question.

Comment: The %f is the really important part. I've had a pre-made .desktop file which wasn't working because the %f was missing - it means that the application accepts file locations being passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to add an application to Ubuntu 20.04 to play SID-tunes. The solution was to add the missing %f as mentioned by @hbt, but in my case the path to the ".desktop"-files were different.

The path to my .desktop-files were: **/usr/share/applications/**

So, to add the application to the "**Open With**"-menu in Ubuntu, I ran:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/zxTune.desktop
```

And then simply added the missing **%f** on the **Exec** line, and it worked like a charm!

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=ZX Tune
Comment=ZX Spectrum music player
Exec=zxtune-qt %f
Icon=zxtune.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Qt;AudioVideo;Audio;Player;
```